# Agda stdlib Vec fromList of list with arbitrary length

Tags: list, agda

I'm trying to use `Data.Vec` `fromList` on a `Data.List` of arbitrary length:

```
natListToVec : {n : ℕ} → List ℕ → Vec ℕ n
natListToVec nats = v.fromList nats
```

but get the error:

```
l.foldr (λ _ → suc) 0 nats != n of type ℕ
when checking that the expression fromList nats has type Vec ℕ n
```

When I try with a `List` that has a known length I don't get any issue:

```
ListWith2ToVec : v.fromList (2 l.∷ l.[]) ≡ 2 v.∷ v.[]
ListWith2ToVec = refl
```

I'm guessing the problem is that with this type signature:

```
{n : ℕ} → List ℕ → Vec ℕ n
```

I don't specify that n must be the length of the `List ℕ`.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `length` function in the type signature. You also have to name the argument of type list to refer to it, like so:

```
natListToVec : (xs : List ℕ) → Vec ℕ (length xs)
[...]
```

Comment: Oh right, I just checked the type signature of Vec.fromList and it's `fromList : (xs : List A) → Vec A (List.length xs)` which is exactly the same (modulo the carrier type)